# How to bind a Collection in an List of Objects in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a Collection of Objects and in each Object is a List of Properties (`PropertyChanges`). This Items should be listed under the "listViewPropertyDetails" `Listview`, but not even the converter "propertyChangeConverter" gets any object to convert. Any other Property in the Object is bindable like Username for example. But if i try to bind the Collection "PropertyChanges" nothing is shown an the converter don't get triggered. what have I forgotten? I am searching hours and don't find the right answer. Hope someone can help me.

```
public class ObjectHistory
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOccurred { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyChange> PropertyChanges = new List<PropertyChange>();
}

public class PropertyChange
{      
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }    
}
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HistoryObjectList">
    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
        <Expander.Header>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource historyObjectHeaderConverter}">
                <Binding Path="DateOccurred"/>
                <Binding Path="Username"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Grid Name="grid1"
              Height="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Name="LabelpropertyChanges"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="15,25,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Padding="0,0,0,0"
                   Content="PropertyChanges"
                   ></Label>                        
            <ListView Name="listViewPropertyDetails"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="15,25,0,0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                                  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyChanges, Converter={StaticResource propertyChangeConverter}}"                                  
                      >                            
                <ListView.View>                            
                <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="PropertyName"

                                             Width="120"
                                             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="OldValue"
                                             Width="265"
                                             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OldValue}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="NewValue"
                                             Width="265"
                                             DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NewValue}"/>
                    </GridView>  
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyChanges` is not defined as a property but as a field and you cannot bind to fields. You should define it like this:

```
public List<PropertyChange> PropertyChanges { get; set; } = new List<PropertyChange>();
```